# What happens with Countess Mignole if you talk to her before her beau dies?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I was going through the quest [Open Sesame!](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Open_Sesame!_(Hearts_of_Stone)) when I ran into Countess Mignole.

> She asked about Vesimir and I responded that he died a hero.

What happens if you initiate this conversation before he dies? Do you only get new dialogue or do you get a quest to reunite the star-crossed lovers before he dies? Unfortunately the linked wiki doesn't discuss this even though it does discuss different options in a later quest [Whatsoever a Man Soweth...](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Whatsoever_a_Man_Soweth%E2%80%A6). This makes me think that the devs at least explored the idea of you getting to Open Sesame before meeting up with Ciri, and might have opened up the possibility of reuniting him with Countess Mignole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She asks how he is.

Geralt responds that he hasn't had a mate in decades.

Mignole states that it was a pity that she never rode after him and let him go.

[You can view the scene here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFh2cKeCLQI)